# Vsce update extension, Access Denied

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to update my VSCode extension, but
    vsce publish
gives me this output:

> Error: Access Denied: [name] needs the following 
>       permission(s) on the resource /[publishername]/[projectname] to 
>       perform this action: Make changes to, share, or view certificate of an 
>       existing extension

I tried to create a new personal access token, (yes, I selected "All accessable organisations" and I also selected "all scopes". The error still occurs. Any ideas?

Comment: Same problem here. vsce has always been painful!